# Why does this cube move in the Y-axis even after rotating it?

Tags: axis

I'm sure that this is something related to global and local axes but I don't know how to implement that in blender. When you play my animation, you will see that the cube doesn't follow it's new local y axis. It follows the global y axis. How can I change that?
**[Click here to download my .blend file](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/qYGiEUzIHppocScCUDJfWgzpk7T.blend)**

Comment: That's how it is supposed to happen, you can only save animation datas on the world axis, except for bones, which are children of the armature, or if you make your object child of another object, it can be an empty, then if you rotate the empty the object will rotate as well and follow the axis of its parent, the world axis won’t matter any more. So depending on your goal it might be sometimes useful to use bones or empties.

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for commenting. My goal is to create a walcking cycle for a character and make it turn left/right. I just wanted to test turing left and right with this box but It didn't work.

Comment: @moonboots For bones, if I animated the root bone (that bone that animated the whole armatre), would it move as I expect? or would it move like the cube?

Comment: for a walk cycle the best is to give a Follow Path constraint to your armature so that it follows a curve

Comment: @moonboots One more question, please. When I think of the turning left or right while using Follow Path constraint, I feel like the foot of the character will slip or slide every time the radious of the curve changes. So, I need to adjust that every time the character turns left or right. Am I right about that? I hope I'm not :)

Comment: yes I guess you need to create a particular animation for when he turns left or right and push it down into the NLA so that it replaces the straight walk   :/

Comment: but maybe the Follow Path is not the best solution and it would be better to just duplicate and move the poses forward? I really depends on your movie sequence...